# Primefaces Image Upload with Image Cropper

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to build a page to register a user. On the page I need the user to upload a profile image. After uploading,the user should be required to crop the image. There are also additional things for the user to input on the page like email, name etc..

So far I have put the upload component, the cropper and all the other inputs in the same h:form. I am using the image uploader in "auto" mode. After uploading, the cropper automatically displays the uploaded image and the cropper region appears.

However, the cropper action method does not get invoked when I click Crop.A "conversion error{0}" is displayed in the growl on the screen.

This error appears even if the Crop() method is completely empty.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong..please could someone advise?

Comment: Can you post your code please, like that we cant see where is the problem!

Comment: Going to implement the cropping with JCrop rather